# Como solucionar este problema de ventanas alargadas en W10?

Tags: windows, windows10

quisiera saber una solución a este problema en el que algunos programas se ven mal, intente usar compatibilidad para ver si se arreglaba pero no, y antes si funcionaban de forma totalmente normal, anexo imágenes con ejemplo de lo sucedido

Normalmente reiniciando a veces se corrige y se ven normales de nuevo, pero quisiera saber si hay alguna solución para que ya no suceda.

[image: Ejemplo problema en winrar]

[image: ejemplo problema en instalador photoshop]

Comment: Eh... son programas que tienes instalados? O programas que tú programaste?

Comment: Programas instalados, en las fotos uno es winrar, y otro es photoshop cs6, en el cs5 me pasaba similar

Answer (score 0):

Probá yendo a Acceso Directo->Propiedades->Acceso Directo(Ventanas de arriba)->Opcion ejecutar: -> Ventana normal

Comment: Así esta, e intente ponerlo en modo de compatibilidad y sigue igual, al reiniciar la pc se arregla pero a veces vuelve a ponerse así las ventanas y debo reiniciar de nuevo

Comment: Te suele pasar al tener muchas cosas abiertas?

Comment: Solo tenia abierto chrome y photoshop, es como que funcionan normalmente pero a veces un día de repente se ponen así y es necesario reiniciar, independientemente de si solo tengo una de esas aplicaciones abiertas o varias.

Comment: Mmm.. y probaste intentando volverlas a su formato apretando ALT+F12?